# Url redirect to folder only if it exist

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I want to use the Url rewriting to convert this :

http://test.com/mypage

To

- If mypage.html or .php exist in the root redirect go for it. http://test.com/mypage.php
- Else if mypage.html or .php doesn't exist in the root, check in the /pages/ folder if it exist. http://test.com/pages/mypage.php
- Else if it doesn't exist in the root and the /pages/ folder just show the 404 error page http://test.com/404.php

I already have some code for the ErrorDocument 404, www. removing and the .php and .html extension removing

```
ErrorDocument 404 http://test.net/404

Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www.test.net [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://test.net/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ $1.html [L]

Options -Indexes
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.php

Options +FollowSymLinks -Indexes
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}  ^www\.(test\.net)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://%1/$1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.html [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/pages/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ pages/$1.php [L]
```